What is the error in my Prime number code?
import java.util.*;
class PrimeNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int d = 2;    
    while(d < n) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            System.out.println("Composite");
        }
        else {
            d++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Prime");
}
}

I have been learning Java for about a week and got a question from my senior to make a programme which distinguishes a prime and a composite number and I tried to make one but did not get the desired output. Printing works well for prime numbers but not for composite it prints composite endlessly for non-prime numbers. I tried to add a break statement out of the composite print statement, but it is not working. It prints composite first and adds a prime also for composite numbers for that I tried to put the prime print statement outside the while loop but even that is not working. And I am frustrated now. Please someone solve my problem.

We want to break; out of the loop when we found a composite number. I recommend reading a tutorial on the topic, e.g. this one from docs.oracle.com.

This is a case where you would learn more by using a debugger. A debugger allows you to set a break point at int d = 2; and then run the code one-line-at-a-time while monitoring variables.  When you come to a conditional (while, if), look at the variables, and predict what the code will do next.  If you want to become a professional software developer, or otherwise regularly develop software, debugging will be a necessary skill. For more thoughts on using a debugger see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems

You have to tell the program to exit after you find that the number is not a prime:
import java.util.*;

class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int d = 2;    
        while(d < n) {
            if(n % d == 0) {
                System.out.println("Composite");
                return;
            }
            else {
                d++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime");
    }
}

Note the return after your print. This will allow the program to stop processing after it has determined that your number is a composite.
At the moment your code simply never stops if it is a composite, and even adding the break statement that you mentioned will only exit from the while loop, but since "Prime" is printed outside of that loop it would still be printed.

Your code currently enters an infinite loop if n % d == 0 (because you stop incrementing on the if branch). As is, your program would be hard to modify if you wanted to test multiple values. I would move the primality test to a method, I would name it isPrime. Next, you only need to test values up to the square root of n. And if you test 2 before your loop you can eliminate all even values. Something like,
private static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(n); i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

And then main is easy to change for an infinite loop allowing the user to test arbitrary values.
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a value to test (-1 to quit): ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    if (n == -1) {
        break;
    }
    String msg = "Composite";
    if (isPrime(n)) {
        msg = "Prime";
    }
    System.out.printf("%d is %s%n", n, msg);
}


There is no need to calc Math.sqrt(n) all the time in the loop, hence it is const.

Your while will always ran as long as d < n. When you find composite you are printing the information, but the values for d or n never change after that therefore the condition in your loop will always be true and the else statement inside your loop will never be executed.
You can add return; statement after System.out.println("Composite"); to exit your program.
import java.util.*;
class PrimeNumber {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int d = 2;    
    while(d < n) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            System.out.println("Composite");
            return;
        }
        else {
            d++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Prime");
}
}


If I'm correct, I think that the loop condition is wrong. The loop doesnt stop when a divisor is found. A break statement would probably be the best solution here. Also "composite" and "prime" could be both printed because they are in the loop. Also, numbers under 2 are not primes so I think you should add logic for that too ;)

According to your code after you get prime number you do not show your output because your loop not stop.So your output is not show .so you need to add return statement for your code .please remake your program below method
    import java.util.*;
    class PrimeNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int d = 2;    
    while(d < n) {
    if(n % d == 0) {
    System.out.println("Composite");
    }
    else {
    d++;
    }
    }
    System.out.println("Prime");
   }
    }


One of the correct and easiest approach is to use a flag (isPrime) with the default value as true. As soon as you see that the number is not a prime set the flag to false and in the end check the flag and print the output accordingly.
import java.util.*;
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int d = 2;
    boolean isPrime = true;
    while(d < n) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
        ++d;
    }
    System.out.println(isPrime ? "Prime" : "Composite");
}


Your code stuck in an endless loop because the statement d++, which increases the d variable, only gets executed in the else block. But when the if() block gets executed, neither n nor d is changing. This means that the condition d < n is never changed either. The result will always be true (once entered) and the check if(n % d == 0) will also be true (once entered). You have to move the d++ statement to a place where it is always executed. You might consider using a for() loop to count from 2 to n.
Additionally you have a System.out.println("Prime"); at the bottom which is printed when the while() loop exits. Even if you found a composite number and exit the while() loop, you will still print this "Prime" line unconditionally. That's why it always say "Prime" in such a situation. Depending on how you structure your code, you might use a helper variable isPrime of type bool to check first if the number is prime or not. After that, check the value of the isPrime variable and print "Prime" or "Composite".
